# VMware Workstation Pro: Is there a feature matrix for Windows guests?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Is there a feature matrix available for VMware Workstation Pro guests?

**The situation**: Have to deploy a virtual environment at a client. They have a valid Windows 7 and Windows 8 license, and they are also ready to buy a Windows 10 license - if I say so.
But, which Windows guest would provide the most features, the most 3D features as a guest?

Tried searching the release notes of Workstation, the documentation, but found nothing.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked on the site, so please don't bite. Comment, edit, help out. Please. Thanks!

Comment: Going with the [Pro Version](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/features) seems like it would be the best option for 3D,DirectX 10 and OpenGL 3.3 as well as other features. And is very compatible for windows 10 if the client chooses to go with that option.  As for a Feature Matrix  I cant come across one so it may be just with the versions.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Yeah I made a big mistake there, I meant the Pro version - I just used it for a very long time and totally forgot about the name change. Sorry! Will correct.